# FirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived method not called for DATA payload in background

Tags: java, android, firebase

i am sending data payload to my android device from firebase function but it is only received when foreground but not in background. It means onMessageReceived is not called when app is cleared/closed/killed. I am sending like below:

```
const payload = {
                data: {
                    title: "Notification Received",
                    body: "body"
                }
            };
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(device_token, payload)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('salman called');
                    return null;
                });
```

i have declared my service like this:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

below is my code of service

```
public class MyService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public String number = "";

    Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("main", MODE_PRIVATE);
        number = sharedPreferences.getString("number", "");

        if (!number.isEmpty()) {
            mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            mFirestore.collection("users").document(number).update(
                    "notification_id", s
            );
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.i("salman", "here");

        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message recieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("main", MODE_PRIVATE);
        number = sharedPreferences.getString("number", "");

        if (!number.isEmpty()) {
            mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            mFirestore.collection("users").document(number).update(
                    "reporting_time", new Timestamp(new Date()),
                    "check", "abc"
            );
        } else {
            Log.i("salman", "number empty");
        }



    }


}
```

This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text This is text this is text

Comment: could you share the full code for FirebaseMessagingService class

Comment: @BiroNader Yes, i added code of service, please take a look.

Comment: onMessageReceived run on background thread  by default  because its android service  so you don't need another thread by handler remove the handler  code and try again

Comment: @BiroNader can you please explain the reason?

Comment: @BiroNader handler is only for testing, when there was no handler, it did not called either.

Comment: To test it right send a test notification from firebase console not from your backend